# how to load 30GB of datasets loading in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

i have a dataset of 30GB which I need to upload  to google colab. What is the process to upload it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do you mean by "Have a 30GB dataset". If this dataset is on your local machine, then you need to:

- Upload your dataset to Google Drive first
- Then mount your Google Drive to your colab-notebook.

If you have the dataset on a server online, then you need to:

- Mount your google drive to your notebook
- Then, download it to your google drive directly

You can use this cod to mount your google-drive to your notebook:

```
import os
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
ROOT = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"
os.chdir(ROOT)
```

If your data is on a server, then you can download it directly by running the following code in a notebook cell.

```
!wget [dataset_url]
```

Comment: yes, i have a 30GB dataset in my local and the drive storage capacity is 20GB then how i upload the dataset without upgrade the drive storage capacity.And then i have to use those 30 GB dataset in google colab.

Comment: buy it ...I suspect you will have tons of performance issues anyway with shared hw on such a large set.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is not enough space, you can change to a GPU runtime to get 350 GB space.

`MENU > Runtime > Change runtime type > Hardware accelerator = GPU`

The process is the same as @Anwarvic 's answer.

Comment: This will depend on the region - I get *less* storage with GPU runtime compared to a CPU one.

Answer (score 0):

you can get more space by changing GPU to TPU from

MENU > Runtime > Change runtime type > Hardware accelerator = **TPU**