# load dataset form Mega Cload to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a big dataset on MEGA cloud storage.
Since I have just 15GB space in google drive, I can not transfer my dataset to google drive. so this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928303/how-to-load-30gb-of-datasets-loading-in-google-colab) is not an option for me

I tried to get the dataset using `! wget [generated link in MEGA]` but it just downloads an HTML file.
Is there any way to mount MEGA cloud to Colab or load my dataset directly from MEGA to Colab (without saving to google drive)?

Answer (score 0):

!cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/{path you want}; wget  [paste the genrated link here] --content-disposition.

Warning- Try at you own discretion